# Translating Ubuntu itself

Tags: translation

I have a question for which I don't seem to be able to find the answer. Where can I find the translations and the translation process of Ubuntu?

I 'm currently in a revival project of the Gothic language and if there is enough demand I could maybe, depending on the amount of text, try to translate a part of Ubuntu in this language. As providing operating systems in this language might be a good step to reviving it.

Answer (score 0):

See https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Ubuntu itself is a project on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) which is a software collaboration platform.

For example [Arabic](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+lang/ar), You have to choose the projects belongs to Ubuntu only like Unity & Ubiquity (which do not have upstream development like Nautilus - Gnome project).